# set picturebox size in form_resize event

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to change size of picturebox(and image inside) when I change size of the form. But when I do like this

```
private void Form2_Resize(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Width = this.Width;
    pictureBox1.Height = this.Height;
}
```

size of picture doesn't change. What is wrong?

Comment: This is typically what `pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `picturebox` is not `docked` try making it docked by setting it's docked `property` then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I think the resize event fires when the form starts to change it's size. Try to delay your picturebox resize logic till the form is done resizing.

Easiest way however would be to use anchors or dock the picturebox...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have hooked the `Form2_Resize` event handler above to the `Resize` event of your form.
Go to the designer, click on the form, and go to the Events list in the properties box, and make sure you select `Form2_Resize` for the `Resize` event.

Other than that, you might want to consider docking the picture box to the form as the others are suggesting.